# how do i retrieve the most recent document added to a collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

using cloud-firestore to store some data from a user calculator, rather than getting all the documents in the collection, how can I just get the most recent?

current set up is:

```
db.collection("calculations")
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              console.log("doc", doc);
              document.getElementById("final-results").innerText +=
                "\n" + doc.data().calcuation;
     });
 });
```

[image of database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzfEz.png)

Comment: Here is a great tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have an internal concept of "most recent document".  The only ordering that Firestore applies to documents are the ones that you define using the fields you add to the document.

If you want a concept of recency, you should include a timestamp type field using a [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) to each document in the collection when you add it to the collection, then query that document using that field.  Then you can use that to [order and limit documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

If you have a timestamp type field called "timestamp" in your documents, this will give you the most recent one:

```
db.collection("calculations")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
```

Comment: Okay good to know, I've added a 'created' field to hold a timestamp for whenever a new document has been created. I'll order it that way.

Comment: OK, please accept this answer as correct if you found it helpful.